# How to connect an input port to an output port in one module through a signal in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I was wondering how to connect in one module, an input port to an output port through a signal.

I want to connect rx422_i in a component titled 'rs422_top' module to tx422_o. I use a signal 'tx422' to bridge between the ports.

However, this produces a synthesis error stating that 'tx422_o' has multiple drivers.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

***The code I have is this:***

```
entity nsgcc_top_rs422 is    
 port (
...
      rx422_i                 : in  std_logic;
      tx422_o                 : out std_logic;
...
);
end nsgcc_top_rs422

signal tx422 : std_logic;

tx422 <= rx422_i;
tx422_o <= tx422;


rs422_inst : rs422_top
 port map (
...
      rx422_i                   => tx422,
      tx422_o                   => tx422,
...
);
```

Comment: signal tx422 does have multiple (two) drivers. One is the input port, rx422_i, the other is the instance, rs422_inst. So, two things are driving tx422. Presumably that's not what you think is happening. What are you expecting?

Comment: Notice Mr. Taylor's answer is predicated on an interpretation of your incomplete code example assuming the code after in the entity declaration is in some architecture specification, there's a missing component declaration and there's a missing `begin` after the signal declaration. (You're code example is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it was someone might provide an actual answer with certainty.

Comment: I agree with user1155120. I deleted my previous answer after it was pointed out that I misunderstood even the part of the question that I was trying to dig out to be helpful. But, I will be happy to put in a new answer if the questioner can ask in a more specific, clear way! =)

Comment: An input port has a driver, you connected that to tx422 through a concurrent signal assignment statement, which produces a driver on tx422. The formal tx422_o produces a driver, and you associate that with the actual tx422 in the component instantiation statement which creates a second driver on tx422..

Comment: Which port of the `rs422_inst` should be connected to which input / output of the `nsgcc_top_rs422` entity?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an actual MCVe based on your code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity rs422_top is
    port (
        rx422_i:    in  std_logic;
        tx422_o:    out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of rs422_top is
begin
    tx422_o <= not rx422_i after 1 ns;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity nsgcc_top_rs422 is    
 port (
      rx422_i:          in  std_logic;
      tx422_o:          out std_logic
);
end nsgcc_top_rs422;

architecture fum of nsgcc_top_rs422 is
    component rs422_top
        port (
        rx422_i:    in  std_logic;
        tx422_o:    out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal tx422:  std_logic; 

begin

    tx422 <= rx422_i;
    tx422_o <= tx422;

rs422_inst:  
    rs422_top
        port map (
            rx422_i => tx422,
            tx422_o => tx422
        );
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity nsgcc_top_rs422_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of nsgcc_top_rs422_tb is
    signal rx422_i: std_logic;
    signal tx422_o: std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.nsgcc_top_rs422
        port map (
            rx422_i => rx422_i,
            tx422_o => tx422_o
        );
STIMULIS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        rx422_i <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        rx422_i <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And it gives a conflict that actually shows up in nsgcc_rs422_top:

[image: nsgcc_rs422_top_tb.png]

Both the input and output to bottom level component rs422_top are 'X'.

Connecting an input to an output:

```
begin

    -- tx422 <= rx422_i;
    tx422_o <= tx422;

rs422_inst:  
    rs422_top
        port map (
            rx422_i => rx422_i, -- tx422,
            tx422_o => tx422
        );
end architecture;
```

gives:

[image: nsgcc_rs422_top_tb_fixed.png]

Which reduces the signal net to one driver (and doesn't connect the rs422_top input to it's output).